# Blazor EventCallback<T> return value to the child component [server-blazor]

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0

I have a need to adjust a child component based on the result of `EventCallback<T>` async call, starting with reporting an error in validation summary. Yet I cannot seem to find a blazor-way to do this efficiently, it seems that communication is strictly one-way, from child to parent.

I read some SO answer that you can use `Func<T1, T2>` instead of `EventCallback<T>`, but that it has a serious downside of not calling `StateHasChanged()` when needed.

```
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> OnAccountEntered { get; set; }

    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        try
        {
            DisableButton = true;
            ButtonText = "Please Wait, Validating Account Information";
            await OnAccountEntered.InvokeAsync(Model.AccountNumber ?? 0).ConfigureAwait(false);
            
            // here be dragons. how do I get the answer from parent?
        }
        finally
        {
            ButtonText = "Request";
            DisableButton = false;
        }
    }
```

What would be the proper way to assure this two-way communication between parent and child object?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Maybe create a method on your child component that can be called by the parent after the EventCallback.
Another option is to add a parameter in your child component for the data you want. When this parameter is changed by the parent, it will automatically rerender the child component.

Comment: What does `OnAccountEntered` in the parent actually do?  Does it change the state of the parent?  Is is just a call to get some data from somewhere else?  On the information provided a `Func<T1, T2>` is a perfectly good solution.  The component will render after `HandleValidSubmit` completes.

Comment: "but that it has a serious downside of not calling StateHasChanged() when needed."   That's not a downside: just a fact.  If you're mutating the state of the component call `StateHasChanged` manually.  It's the same with any standard event handler.

Comment: Why not use `Value`/`ValueChanged` properties in the Child Component and then use the `@bind-Value` feature in the parent markup? This will provide two-way communication for your property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "Serious Downside" or anything wrong with using a `Func` delegate.  You have control over whether or not you refresh the parent component.  Dragons [like the comment] are myths.

Here's a quick demo using a `Func<Task, int>`.

**MyComponent**

```cs
<div class="bg-light m-2 p-2">
    <h3>MyComponent</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.HandleValidSubmit>Update</button>
    <div class="bg-secondary text-white m-2 p-1">
        <pre>Counter: @counter </pre>
    </div>
</div>


@code {
    [Parameter] public Func<int, Task>? OnAccountEntered { get; set; }
    private int counter;

    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        if (this.OnAccountEntered is not null)
        {
            // unless you're an async expert keep the await clean and simple
            await this.OnAccountEntered.Invoke(counter + 1);
            counter++;
            // put in a delay so you can see this component update afer the parent
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

And **Index**

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-1">
    <pre>Counter: @counter </pre>
</div>

<MyComponent OnAccountEntered=this.AccountChanged />

@code{
    private int counter;

    private async Task AccountChanged(int value)
    {
        counter = value;
        // pretend we're an async method getting data from some async source
        await Task.Yield();
        // call StateHasChanged if the process mutates the state of this component
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, in the end, I did it this way. Seemed more Blazor-y than using two way binding (since I have async processing in between). Thanks. Still wish there was a `EventCallback<TRet, T>` option, due to the single subscriber semantics and embedding into Blazor pipeline.